# Python: Possible combinations for items in a list of lists

Tags: python, nested, combinations

Suppose I have a nested list that looks like this:

```
nested_list = [[a,b,1],[c,d,3],[a,f,8],[a,c,5]]
```

Now I want to get all possible combinations between the second items of the lists, but only if the first items in both lists are equal. So what should be printed is the following:

```
Combinations for 'a' as first item in the lists: [b,f], [b,c], [f,c]
```

I came up with this:

```
comprehension = [x[0] for x in nested_list if x[1] in nested_list]
```

But this does not work (ofcourse). I'm not sure how to loop over all lists in order to find the combinations.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collectoins.defaultdict` and `combinations`:

```
In [2]: nested_list = [['a','b',1],['c','d',3],['a','f',8],['a','c',5]]

In [3]: from collections import defaultdict

In [4]: from itertools import combinations

In [5]: d = defaultdict(list)    

In [6]: for i, j, _ in nested_list:
   ...:     d[i].append(j)
   ...:     

In [7]: {k: list(combinations(v, 2)) for k, v in d.items()}
Out[7]: {'a': [('b', 'f'), ('b', 'c'), ('f', 'c')], 'c': []}
```